# Why can't SpeechSynthesis.speak() be called more than once in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, speech-synthesis

I can call SpeechSynthesis.speak() in Chrome multiple times and get some text read out over and over again. However, if i try the exact same code in Firefox, the first call works fine, but subsequent calls are ignored/silently fail.

It only works again once i refresh the page.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experimental technology likely not handled correctly by Firefox.

Try a `SpeechSynthesis.cancel()` before re-iterating your `.speak()` call.

Answer (score 1):

```
objSpeaker = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
```

Must be called every time in Firefox

Answer (score -1):

I gave up Firefox ...
Firefox never stop the speaking so it cannot speak twice..
and even the cancel() command does not work at all.

see below commands on firefox: 
[image: firefox speech synthesis not work]